# The test within the if statement does not catch nulls

Tags: bash

I have tested it with double braces for the "&&" and have tried it against "" for null values however every time it does not move down to the else statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
#find | grep
#find -a {} | grep {search}
function fg { 
        if [ -z $1 ] && [ -z $2 ]; then
        echo "Help: find {path} | grep {search} "

        else
        find $1 | grep $2

        fi 
}

fg
```

Comment: Have you tried with quotes arround the $1 and $2?

Comment: Yes, I have tried every variation I can think of I've assigned the arguments to variables and applied them in the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always quote your parameter expansions.

```
fg () { 
  if [ -z "$1" ] && [ -z "$2" ]; then
    echo "Help: must specify path and regular expression"
  else
    find "$1" -regex "$2"
  fi
}

fg
```

A cleaner way to check for unset or empty parameters, though, is via the `:?` operator.

```
fg () {
    : ${1:?Missing path}
    : ${2:?Missing regex}
    find "$1" -regex "$2"
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use the top block of code but tried the bottom one and hasnt flagged any errors, however I cant verify that it works for me as I'm getting an unexpected token for the closing brace on the function.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,  tried the second block of code and still didn't work?